# Redirect to a Order Success Page once the form has been submitted succesfully

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form which is supposed to be redirected to order success page once the submit button is clicked.
I tried to use hearder() but headers already sent error came. No way I could put this at the top of the php file as I have to redirect to the old order page if the submitted form has errors.

Is there any other way of doing it?

One more doubt,
Currently I am using the following to clear all the sessions!

```
<?php session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true); ?>
```

So do I have to use this `<?php session_start(); ?>` again in the form if I intend to use the session in the same page after the above give n code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a couple of things,

1. Use javascript to redirect the user by outputting `<script type="text/javascript">parent.location.href = 'nextpage.php';</script>`
2. You could use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to send a HTTP Header after outputting.

> While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> You could add a **meta refresh** header `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=nextPage.php">`
>
> You can show the user a link to the next page and let him click on it himself.

Comment: How's that not getting to the issue? :) He asked about the redirection. I did forget a bout the session thing though , but you already took care of that ;-)

Comment: Well it's a bit messy if he doesn't know why headers are being sent out, it's probably unintentional, and if he finds it is intentional, then yes, your solution is good hence the +vote... however, it's not helping find out WHY headers are sent?

Comment: Usually i would think the same but the sentence `No way I could put this at the top of the php file` made me pretty certain that he knows that it should be on top before any output. Anyways, thanks for your notes :)

Answer (score 1):

You are sending headers by content being sent to the browser, in other words something has been echoed before you tried to header();

Find out what, exit; before you want to header(); to try find out the issue

I would never normally suggest this, because it would be EXTREMELY bad practice, but to force it:

```
ob_clean(); // Cleans the output buffer
header("Location: redirect-url");
```

To clear sessions:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

---

**Update**:

Yes you must use `session_start();` again to re-initiate a NEW session, but remember you destroyed the old one so the data is cleared - A new session = empty session

Comment: @oDx if these answers helped you, please mark one of them as the correct answer ;)